# Deserializing an object from multiple files in C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Is it possible to deserialize a single object from multiple XML files? For example, if I have the following class:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SubClass))]
[XmlRoot]
public class BaseClass
{
    [XmlElement]
    public virtual int CommonSetting { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot]
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    [XmlElement]
    public int OtherSetting { get; set; }
}
```

I want to deserialize an instance of 'SubClass' from XML, but I want to split the definition into two distinct files. For example:

```
BaseClass.xml

<BaseClass>
    <CommonSetting>10</CommonSetting>
</BaseClass>


SubClass.xml

<SubClass>
    <OtherSetting>5</OtherSetting>
</SubClass>
```

And secondly, is it then possible to override inherited 'common' settings by setting them inside the 'SubClass.xml' file. For example, if I defined 'SubClass.xml' as:

```
<SubClass>
    <CommonSetting>5</CommonSetting>
    <OtherSetting>5</OtherSetting>
</SubClass>
```

Then I would like to have an object 'Subclass' with a 'CommonSetting' of 5, rather than 10.

Is the above possible and if so, how can I go about it? Currently all I can achieve is to deserialise an instance of 'BaseClass' and 'SubClass' separately, and 'SubClass' has null/default values for settings derived from 'BaseClass'.

Comment: First, you xml doesn't have a type attribute which is needed for an inherited class.  You can manually parse xml files using either Xmldocument or XDocument which will meet your requirements.  Once imported, you can change class property from 10 to 5.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need inheritance (`SubClass` shouldn't inherit from `BaseClass`). Serialize each class into own xml (e.g. by using `XmlSerializer`), deserialize same way.

Comment: In reality 'BaseClass' will have many settings containing sensible default values. 'SubClass' will, in most cases, accept these defaults. It doesn't make sense for it not to derive from 'BaseClass'. I would end up defining the properties twice.

Comment: "you xml doesn't have a type attribute which is needed for an inherited class." -  The above is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve. I can successfully deserialize the subclass, it just doesn't contain values for settings which are defined in the BaseClass.xml file.